# How to Format the Resume Section Underline in Awesome CV by posquit0?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, resume, underline, awesome-cv, headline

I am Using [This](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV) Resume and I want to change the Resume Sections Headline Underline from Current (Where it starts after the text end) to the Normal underline we see in Resume i.e just below the Text not in Front of it. Can anyone Help me out on this?[image: Adding Image for Reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code before `\begin{document}`

```
\renewcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
    \vspace{\acvSectionTopSkip}
    \sectionstyle{#1}\\[-0.8\baselineskip]
    \phantomsection
    \color{gray}
    \rule{\linewidth}{.9pt}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
}
```

[image: a]